# If T(n)=θ(n^2) equals T(n)=0(n)?

Tags: algorithm

If T(n) = θ(n^2) = O(n^2) = Ω(n^2) equals:
`T(n)=O(n)`?
`T(n)=O(n^3)`?

Looking for answers but once:

> O(n2), it is also O(n2log n), O(n3), O(n4) and so on, but is not O(n)

then:

> Big O means your algorithm will execute in no more steps than in given
>   expression(n^2)

Comment: What's your question? If it is the title, then the answer is no. θ(n^2) means algorithm will execute in n^2 steps. No less, no more.

Comment: if it equals T(n)=O(n) or T(n)=O(n^3). One of this answers should be correct

Comment: If T(n)=θ(n^2), then T(n)=O(n^3). Refer to your textbooks.

Comment: The biggest mistake that instructors (and too many commenters on this website) keep making about complexity classes is the use of equality rather than set membership.

Comment: @Rhymoid it's standard to write f(n) = O(g(n)). It's an abuse of notation, and perhaps it was a mistake to standardize on this notation, but it's not a mistake to use it anymore.

Comment: @PaulHankin That argument is basically "we've always done it like that". It's a harmful abuse of notation. It's not actually shorter, and seeing how students always have issues with big-O until they realise it's a complexity *class*, it's definitely worse than the more rigorous version. It's still a mistake to use it, because the standard is counter-productive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's true.

If `T(n) = θ(n^2)` ,

then

`T(n) = O(n^k)` where `k>=2`

`T(n) = Ω(n^k)` where `k<=2`

Note that if `T(n) = θ(n^2)` the `T(n) != θ(n^3)` as `T(n) = θ(n^2)` means growth rate of `n` is asymptotically equal to the growth rate of `n^2`.

Whereas if `T(n) = O(n^2)` then `T(n) = O(n^3)` because `T(n) = O(g(n))` means growth rate of T(n) is asymptotically less than or equal to to the growth rate of g(n). So, if growth rate of T(n) is less than growth rate of `n^2` then obviously it will be less than that of `n^3`.